# Fund transferred to smart contract address not showing in balances

Tags: balances, account, pallet-contracts

I deploy an ink smart contract through a properly configured `pallet_contracts` **(4.0.0-dev from the Substrate branch polkadot-v0.9.29)** on chain. Then I use the unique address of that smart contract and through `pallet_balances`, transfer some funds to that address. If I now go to the contracts panel in `polkadot.js.org/apps (version 0.122.2)`, the transferred fund shows up for that contract instance. However if I check the chain state of the `pallet_balances` for that address, it is still 0 (both free and reserved). My question is why? Is it a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of storing balances in Substrate. One way is to store the balance in the pallet_balances where you were looking, and the other is to store the balance in the [frame system](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/frame_system/lib.rs.html#530).

When you implement the pallet_balances in the runtime you specify where you want to store it, for example in the [template node](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L254).

If you take a look into the runtime of your node: runtime/src/lib.rs you will see it:

```
type AccountStore = System;
```

If you want more info about this topic check the [Subtrate docs](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/account-data-structures/).

So to get the balance you have to check the chain state of the system for that address.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the account balance info via chainstate->system->account(acountID). Not sure why balances pallet account data gives result with 0 values.